# Bounded functions and infimum/supremum

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Question from my homework:

> A function $f \colon S \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *decreasing* on the domain $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ if for every $x, y \in S$ with $y > x$, we have $f(y) < f(x)$.
>   Show that if $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, then the limits $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ both exist.
>
> *Caution: While this claim is clearly related to the theorem that bounded monotone sequences always converge, it is not an immediate corollary of it.
>   You will have to use the definition of the limit directly.*
>
> (Original picture of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxZfl.png).)

My proof:

Let $ S = \{f(x) | x \in \mathbb{R} \} $, since $f$ is bounded this set has both an infimum and supremum. (Is this true? I tried to prove it, but have no idea as it seems fairly obvious.) Now, I claim that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \inf(S) = L$.

By definition, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x>K \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Now since $f(x) \geq L$ by definition of the infimum, choose $x_1$ such that $f(x_1) < L + \epsilon$ for $x_1 > K$. But since $f$ is a decreasing function we have $f(x) \leq f(x_1)$, and thus
$$
  L - \epsilon < L \leq f(x) \leq f(x_1) < L + \epsilon
$$
which proves our claim.

I use a similar argument for the supremum. Could anyone help me out on making this more rigorous as I feel as though I've skipped some steps.

Comment: Any bounded set in the real numbers has a sup and an inf. If they are in the set themselves is a different story.

Comment: About supremum and infimum you are ok. Now, you are wrong in your way to prove that the limit exists,because you don't prove that such a $K$ exists. All you have to do is to prove this existence.

Comment: I don't able to see your question

Comment: anyone edit so that I try to solve that question

Comment: You might want to look up the monotone convergence theorem.  This theorem applies to sequences and not functions, but there are enough similarities that you can lift the proof.  One item you have not stated is what if there is no $x$ such that $f(x)<L+\epsilon$?  But that would contradict that $L$ is the infimum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. I would proceed like this:
For $\epsilon > 0$ be a given, there exists an $x^{*}$ such that $f(x^{*}) < L + \epsilon $. So let $K = |x^{*}| + 1 > 0$, then for all $x$'s such that $x > K$ we have: $f(x) < f(K) < f(x^{*}) < L + \epsilon$. But $L < f(x)$ since it is $\text{inf}\{f(x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. So
$L - \epsilon < L < f(x) < L + \epsilon$. This means $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ and we're done.